# Will I lose my item if I try to trade the same thing with Snuggly the Crow twice?

Tags: dark-souls

Some of the trades are really nice, but I've heard that you can only do a trade once, and I don't want to lose my items if that's true.

Comment: Trades are only limited to once per playthrough (making it possible to do most of the good trades each new game, as they take unique items, unless of course you think some of the other trades are 'good' from the non-unique item trades). It's been a while since I did snuggly trades, but I am pretty sure the answer is no.

Comment: why don't you post that as an answer, you don't get credit otherwise.

Comment: Because it does not really answer the question asked as I do not know for certain the mechanic.

Comment: ok, point taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure you don't drop the entire stack of items, and drop them one at a time.

if you drop them all in one go, they'll be used up as one item iirc.

As per the commenters, after dropping one item, and receiving one from Snuggly, you need to reload the area either by leaving, or saving and reloading to continue to trade.

Comment: But as long as I drop one item, then reload the game i'll be fine?

Comment: I don't think you even need to reload the game, but check youtube videos or something to be sure!.

Comment: i think it's either reload the game or leave the undead asylum and come back.

Comment: To clarify - yes; you can only trade one item at a time, but there is no limit to how many times that item can be traded. As for the exchange; you do need to reload the area (by either quitting or leaving then coming back)